# Register hotkey with modifiers from keyboard input

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys

Im creating a C# Windows Forms application where I have a button which registeres a hotkey to the input the user gives.

Before pressing:

[image]

After pressing:

[image]

Without modifiers it works fine, I'm taking the input, unregister the old hotkey and register the new one with the keycode I got from the user.

Now `Form1_KeyUp` also provides the modifiers, reading them works fine aswell but when I try to register the new hotkey with the given modifiers it doesn't work, probably because `RegisterHotkey()` uses a different "format" for the hotkeys. So the actualy question is: How do I convert the modifiers given in the `KeyUp` event to a format I can use in `RegisterHotkey()`?

Heres my code:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (buttonHotkeyWaiting)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            buttonHotkey.Text = (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(S_HOTKEY);
        else
        {
            S_HOTKEY = (int)e.KeyCode;
            S_HOTKEY_MODS = (int)e.Modifiers;

            string modString = (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(e.Modifiers);
            buttonHotkey.Text = modString.Substring(0, modString.Length - 4) + (new KeysConverter()).ConvertToString(S_HOTKEY);

            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1);
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, S_HOTKEY_MODS, S_HOTKEY);

            MessageBox.Show(S_HOTKEY_MODS.ToString());
        }

        Cursor.Show();
        buttonHotkeyWaiting = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to translate the modifier information into the integer used by the user32.dll:

```
int mod = 0;
if (e.Alt) mod |= 1;
if (e.Control) mod |= 2;
if (e.Shift) mod |= 4;
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, mod, S_HOTKEY);
```